# Button alignment in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having the view pager and page indicator as following. I am trying to keep buttons above the view pager on either sides of it. But i am not able to get those buttons on left and right sides. Can some one please help me to keep those buttons on at proper positions.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
      >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/dots"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            local:tabBackground="@drawable/dot_selector"
            local:tabGravity="center"
            local:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            local:tabPaddingStart="7dp"
            local:tabPaddingEnd="7dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/skipBtn"
                android:text="Skip"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
                android:text="Next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

While running this codes the buttons are not appearing.

Comment: can you please show me an image or something that looks like what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your linear layout in both of your buttons use android:layout_weight="1"

This will basically specify the size ratio between the two buttons in the layout as equal.

see here for more layout weight styling details: https://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-2/